# GeoIP stopped working in v10 due to missing Country rule

Tags: geo-location

There was rule `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Obsolete/Common/Conditions/GeoIP/Country` in v9.3 whish has been deprecated and removed in v10 (item id `{331C6356-630C-4F5B-AF4B-7B21DBDAA3D7}`).

What should be used insted?

Comment: you can add your own answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Country rule `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/GeoIP/Country` (`{52E42C59-7210-43E5-94A6-3EA6B98835B8}`). Just replaced the old one with the new one and GeoIP works now.

**Update:** In v10 there was a list of broken links in presentation referencing old Country rule. In order to fix them, on v10, I *installed* and immediately *removed* the old rule item. Delete dialog allowed me to re-link broken references to the new Country rule (kudos to SC support).